# Variable for $_GET array not returning any values

Tags: php, arrays, phpmyadmin, get

I can't seem to return any values on my $_GET array.

It works fine when e.g.
**`$sql = "SELECT * FROM review WHERE brand='brandx'"`** but when I change it to **`brand='$id'`** in line 5, nothing gets passed.

The fetch array in my index.php works perfectly fine however when it gets href to brand.php (as shown below), I lose my marbles.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["id"])){
include "php_includes/db_conx.php";
$id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET["id"]);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM review WHERE brand='$id'";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$productList = ""; 
// Now make sure that brand exists in the table
$productCount = mysqli_num_rows($query);// count the output amount
if($productCount > 0){
//get the products off the selected brand
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
$username = $row['username'];
$productname = $row['productname'];
$comment = $row['comment'];
$rating = $row['rating'];
$date = $row['date'];
$productList .= 
'
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="brand-and-name">
    <div class="brand">
        <a href="brand.php?id='.$id.'">
        <span>'.$id.'</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="prod-name">
        <a href="product.php">'.$productname.'</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="prod-container" id="pd1">
        <div class="prod-img"><img     src="https://giovanniphotography.files.wordpress.com/2011/09/creativemevid19.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="comment">
            <a href="#"><b>My Score: '.$rating.'/10</b></a>
            <br /><br />
            <p>'.$comment.'</p>
        </div>
        <div class="profile">
            <div class="profile-thumb" id="pt1"></div>
            <div class="name" id="nm1">
                <a href="user.php?user='.$username.'">'.$username.'</a><br />'.$date.'
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="social-share-1">
            <div class="like-btn"></div>
            <div class="comment-btn"></div>
            <div class="wishlist-btn">+ wishlist</div>
        </div>
  </div><!--end .prod-container#pd1-->
</div><!--wrPer-->
';
}
    }else{
    echo "Product doesnt exist";
    exit ();
    }
}else{
echo "You got to pick a brand man!";
exit ();
}
?>
```

Comment: is `$id` supposed to be a numeric value?

Comment: try this `$sql = "SELECT * FROM review WHERE brand=".$id;`

Comment: Please tabulate your code properly before posting a question, that mess is hard to look at.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); `then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: ...and `$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($db_conx));`

Comment: also make sure your row contain lowercase values. `brandx` and `Brandx` are two different animals altogether. Best you show db schema, or take it up with the one who's provided you with an "answer" below. Checking for errors in your query will tell you that. View your HTML source and use `var_dump();` and make sure your row(s) don't contain any trailing spaces.

Comment: you've another answer to deal with. I'm out of this loop. *ciao*

Comment: Btw, how ARE you echoing `$productList`? that's probably your "answer" right there. Do I see a "facepalm" here? `echo $productList .=..... `

Answer (score 0):

Does this code work, after your preg_replace?  If not you may not have magic quotes enabled in php.ini.  I notice in the rest of your output you are concatenating strings and variables.

```
print "ID: $id";
```

Comment: *"Does this work..."* types of answers are considered as "comments".

Comment: @andrew-coder When I looked at php.ini and there was the culprit itself. Am reading about magic quotes now itself.

Answer (score 0):

use a prepared statement and dont hassle with sanitizing of user input:

```
if($stmt = $db_conx->prepare("SELECT username, productname, comment, rating, date FROM review WHERE brand=?)")
{
    $stmt->bind_value('s', $_GET["id"]);
    $result = $stmt-execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($username, $productname, $comment, $rating, $date ); //bind result to vars
    //now you can loop through your result:
    while($stmt->fetch()) {
        //use $username, $productname, $comment, $rating, $date etc to work with your values
    }
}
```

Comment: why should they use that? They're not getting values in their GET array in the first place. *Sheeshhh*.